# How to make REST API calls to Amazon Alexa skills which uses a non-custom model

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Currently I am working with Alexa education skills, in order to connect a pre-built education skill with my own rest API. I came across with multiple tutorials which explains how to connect a custom skill (with Intents) to a rest API and get data, but I was unable to find any tutorials which explain about education **(probably non-custom skills).**

The way of invoking a non-custom skill is not understood because they do not use intents.

Please can anybody kindly suggest a way to connect a remote API to a non-custom skill, or any tutorials regarding this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of non-custom skills you think about?

Comment: I need to know about education skills (a skill which uses education as the model)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/education/steps-to-create-education-skill.html) for that. According to [that](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/education/steps-to-create-education-skill.html#write-code), you should create your own lambda function in order to handle Education skill requests - there you can call your API.

Education skills have pre-built [utterances](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/education/about-education-skills.html#utterances):

```
Alexa, what are my grades?
Alexa, how are the kids doing in school?
Alexa, what do I have due tomorrow?
Alexa, what does Hannah have due next week?
Alexa, do I have any chemistry homework?
Alexa, what did Hannah do in school today?
Alexa, are there any posts from my professors?
```

Comment: Thanks :)  I followed [this](https://github.com/jamielliottg2/ChuckNorrisAPIAlexaSkill/blob/master/lambda/us-east-1_aws-serverless-repository-alexaskillskitnodejsfact-E5NGAG29UVN2/index.js) in order to learn how to make REST API calls to an Amazon custom skill. But I really do not understand how to make the same code applicable to an Education skill.

Comment: Actually, I am having the problem of invoking an Education skill, because no **intents** are used  there.

Comment: It works a little bit different see [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/education/steps-to-create-education-skill.html#enable-skill). I edited the answer - there are built-in intents, you can call using pre-built utterances.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will refer the documentation